# Open Kibana Console with queries from JSON file?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is it possible to save a bunch of queries into a single JSON file to import in Kibana Console?

I know there's an option to save a single query[2] and the Kibana console is based on local storage, but I would like to load up the queries based on parameters, such that changing the params(e.g `load_from=filename.json`) should load up a different set of queries.

For example, when I open `http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console?load_from=filename.json`, it should open the Kibana console with ES queries from the file.

EDIT: As a workaround, it's possible to do this with Postman API Client or similar API clients.

**Solution**:

EDIT 2 on 22/02/2022: Kibana Spaces is the answer. It lets you organize dashboards and other saved objects into meaningful categories[3]. Whenever you load http://localhost:5601/ it lets you choose the space you want to work with. Having multiple browser tabs with different saved spaces should work for most cases.

[2] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/save-load-delete-query.html

[3] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/xpack-spaces.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible yet.

Elastic is (supposedly) working on a new Kibana feature ([tabbed console panes #10095](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/10095)) that will provide support for better organizing the code in the Dev Tools application. The issue has been opened for a while and not much seems to be happening, so we'll see.

The release date of that feature is not known yet.

Comment: Thanks for the issue link @Val! Is there any workaround using a plugin or something of that sort?

Comment: I don't think so... or at least not that I know of...

Comment: It's good to know that something like this isn't possible with the current version of Kibana. Not the answer I was looking for, but thanks, anyway! Upvoted & accepted!

Comment: Indeed, the answer reflects the current state, not what you wanted to hear :-) I'll make sure to update it once something suiting your needs gets available